# Corda On General Data Protection Regulation

Tags: blockchain, corda

Recently I was going through GDPR and Blockchain compliances. It seems that GDPR going to bring pretty much changes in Blockchain Data storing concepts. So I would like to know what steps Corda is taking for making it GDPR compliance? any future release?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did not get you .. the link is not opening ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question.

Long story short Corda is GDPR compliant, but remember that Corda is a tool for you to deploy a network to share information with other parties that you wish to share information with. It is also incumbent on you, the network operator to ensure that you are GDPR compliant in your particular use case.

R3 (developer of corda) has put out a whitepaper on the subject, here's a link to it : https://www.r3.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/GDPR_Blockchains_R3.pdf

best of luck to you.